# How is it known that Aenesidemus the major sceptic philosopher was from Knossos?

Tags: history-of-philosophy, skepticism

Aenesidemus is considered one of the major skeptic ancient philosophers but according to wikipedia little is known about his life.

How is it known that Aenesidemus the major sceptic philosopher was from Knossos?

Comment: There are sources regarding history of Ancient Philosospy: the main one is [Diogenes Laertius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diogenes_Laertius). See reference to [*Lives of Eminent Philosophers*: "Life of Timon of Phlius", Book IX, Chapter 12 Section 116](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0258%3Abook%3D9%3Achapter%3D12)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to The Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy, [Anna-Barnes (1985)](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/modes-of-scepticism/D82516C6783D9831B83B49B132080C37) notes that Sextus Empiricus ascribes the 10 Modes of Scepticism to Aenesidemus.

The [Stanford Entry](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/skepticism-ancient/#AenTenModApp) also notes that Aenesidemus was involved with The Academy, becoming discontented with the dogmatic proto-externalism found therein.

I suppose one could search the writings / histories of other members of the academy at the time Aenesidemus was involved in order to find evidence of an "Aenesidemus of Knossos".

Comment: Is there any indication that anyone of Aenesidemus'  contemporaries ever referenced him in his works?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I'll report back if I ever happen across anything.